# Search and Replace Keyword with File Name across Multiple Files

Tags: search, replace, filenames

I am trying to do a mass search and replace across many files where I replace a keyword in the file, lets say `myKeyword`, with the name of the current file.

So in file1.php the phrase `myKeyword` would become `file1`;
in `file2.php` it would become `file2`;
and so on until all the files are completed.

I was wondering if this is possible using scripts or a text editor function.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
$ for filename in $(find . -type f -name "*"); do sed -i "s/myKeyword/$(basename ${filename} | cut -f 1 -d '.')/g" "${filename}"; done
```

- `basename`: strip full path from filename - `path/to/file1.txt` -> `file1.txt`
- `cut -f 1 -d '.'`: strip file extension - `file1.txt` -> `file1`

On OSX (BSD sed instead of GNU) you'll need to write `sed -i '' "s/myKeyword/...` instead (empty string `''` after `-i`). See this answer for the difference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272041/374001